# What length would the sides of a triangle over Earth's surface be for the sum of its angles to be 180.1°

Tags: geometry, triangles, spheres, spherical-geometry

For simplicity's sake, let the Earth be a perfect sphere. Imagine you are drawing an equilateral triangle over its surface. How long should its sides be, for the sum of its angles to be 180.1 degrees?

Comment: This most certainly depends on your approximation of the Earth's radius.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier : I wouldn't worry about that for present purposes. Just use the radius as the unit of measurement.

Comment: @MichaelHardy yet the question is "how long...", plus given the level of the question, I think that it is worth mentioning.

Comment: I'll edit my answer further and then restore it.

Comment: Look at this page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalExcess.html In thes case $E = .1$ so and $a=b=c= 2s$ as $s=\frac 32a$ so $\tan{ .025} = \sqrt{\tan(\frac 34 a)\tan^3(\frac 14 a)}$ where $a$ is the side of an equilateral triangle.  So solve for $a$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I saw him in my backyard with a paint bucket, but I guess it was not large enough...

Comment: Sorry, browser from Hot Network Questions here... How is the sum of the angles of a triangle ever something other than 180?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The area of a spherical triangle is exactly $ER^2$ where $E$ is the angular excess. In our case $E=\frac{\pi}{1800}$, so the given triangle covers $\frac{1}{7200}$ of Earth's surface. Assuming $R=1$, l'Huilier's formula (page 184 of [my notes)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) relates the angular excess / the area to the semiperimeter / the side lengths through
$$ \tan\frac{E}{4}=\sqrt{\tan\frac{s}{2}\tan\frac{s-a}{2}\tan\frac{s-b}{2}\tan\frac{s-c}{2}} $$
and in our case we have $a=b=c=\ell$ and $s=\frac{3}{2}\ell$, so

$$ E = \frac{\pi}{1800} = 4\arctan\sqrt{\tan\frac{3\ell}{4}\tan^3\frac{\ell}{4}} $$
and by solving
$$ \tan\frac{3\ell}{4}\tan^3\frac{\ell}{4}=\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7200} $$
we get that $\ell$ is approximately $6.347\%$ of the radius $R$.

For Earth, $R =6\ 371$ km, and $\ell = 404.377$ km.

Comment: (+1) Amazing, BTW, is there any thing you don't know?

Comment: How long did it take you to write up those notes? Wow!

Comment: Your "notes" look like 3 PhD theses. And they're actually useful and are read by others. Congrats.

Answer (score 8):

Let $r$ be the radius of the Earth; the area of a triangle between the equator and two meridians $90^\circ$ apart is $\frac{r^2\pi}{2}$ and has a defect of $270^\circ-180^\circ=90^\circ$. Now we want a triangle with $900$ times smaller defect, which means it needs to have $900$ times smaller area: $\frac{r^2\pi}{1800}$.

Now I will *not* calculate the side for the *spherical* equilateral triangle (for the given area) but a *planar* one, expecting (without proof!) that this won't make a lot of difference. Thus, the side is approximately $\sqrt{\frac{4}{\sqrt 3}\frac{r^2\pi}{1800}}=r\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{450\sqrt 3}}\approx 404\text{ km}$.

Comment: Your approximation is 6.7% of the radius, Jack's exact value is 6.3%.  Not a bad approximation.

Comment: @GEdgar, actualy I rounded to the whole km, but the multiplier itself turns out to be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{450\sqrt{3}}}=0.06348752$... so mine is 6.3% too :)

Comment: (+1) And it is not a huge surprise that the solutions of $$\frac{3\ell^4}{256}=\left(\frac{\pi}{7200}\right)^2\quad\text{and}\quad \tan\frac{3\ell}{4}\tan^3\frac{\ell}{4}=\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7200}$$ are pretty close, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider an equilateral spherical triangle with side lengths $a$ and angles $A$, by the supplemental cosine rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Identities

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(A) =- \cos^2(A)+\sin^2(A) \cos(a) \\
\cos(a) =\frac{\cos(A)+\cos^2(A)}{\sin^2(A)} =\frac{\cos(A)}{1-\cos(A)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we have $A=60.0333\cdots$, which gives $a=3.6\cdots$.

To obtain the distance on a sphere of radius $r$ calculate $ra\pi/180$.